# Microsoft office.js Excel add-in - How to implement arrow style for a data series in a line chart?

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

In Office Excel, you have an option to implement an arrow style in your line chart for a data series.

[image]

However, it seems like the office.js library is unable to implement this option.

[Excel.Line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excel/excel.line#properties) has the option I'm looking for (`beginArrowheadLength`, `beginArrowheadStyle`, etc, ), but it was strictly for shapes, completely separate from series charts, and has no way to somehow implement a custom shape to the data series.

So, how can I implement arrow styling for my data series in chart, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @little Doe, 
I am sorry office.js currently do not provide API for beginArrowheadLength, beginArrowheadStyle for line Chart. I have created a work item(3933545) for this feature ask.

You could submit your request in uservoice and upvote for this feature for Excel online at https://officespdev.uservoice.com/

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've submit my request here : https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/39957346-implement-arrow-style-for-a-data-series-in-a-chart